# Why is it allowed to have a class that has an incomplete type static member of itself?

Tags: c++

I am having a hard time understanding why a class can have an incomplete type static member of itself.

For example in my code below. Why is it allowed to have an incomplete type static member of itself inside class A, but the global static variable of class type B gets an error when it is an incomplete type?

```
class B {
public:
    B(int a) {
    }
};

static B test2; //error


class A {

public:
    static A test; //accepted

    A(int d) {
    }
};
```

Can someone explain to me perhaps what is going behind the scenes that gives the global static variable an error and why the static variable inside class A is accepted?

Comment: `B` is not incomplete at the declaration `static B test2;`. Did you make an error copying your example? It fails because of lack of a usable constructor, not incompleteness.

Comment: Are you mixing up "incomplete type" with "no matching constructor"?

Comment: Yes perhaps I am mixing it up. My question should probably be why does the static variable in class A get to be an incomplete type instead of failing due to a lack of a usable constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conflating a couple of dissimilar issues here

```
static B test2; //error
```

fails because `B`'s constructor requires arguments that haven't been provided and is `private` so it can't be accessed outside the class. Correct those and `B` is good to go.

```
class B {
public: // added for outside access to constructor
    B(int a) {
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
};

static B test2{1}; // added arguments
```

As for `A`, a `static` member is not part of a class instance, so the compiler doesn't need it to be complete. It doesn't take up any space, and at this point it's not being used for anything. It's just a declaration. You can declare all sorts of stuff without the compiler getting upset (so long as the declaration's syntax is good). You run into trouble when you try to use something without a definition.

Example:

```
void testfunc(const A &)
{

}

int main(){
    testfunc(A::test);
}
```

fails at the linker because `A::test` was never defined. If you try to correct that with

```
class A {

public:

    static A test{1}; // let's try to define it inline!
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    A(int d, int e) : a(d), b(e), c(15) {

    }

    A(int d) :A(d, 10) {
        printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
    }
};
```

now the compiler cares enough to report that the class is incomplete. We'll have to move the definition outside the class where it is complete

```
class A {

public:

    static A test; //declared
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    A(int d, int e) : a(d), b(e), c(15) {

    }

    A(int d) :A(d, 10) {
        printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
    }
};
A A::test{1}; // defined
```

Now

```
void testfunc(const A &)
{

}

int main(){
    testfunc(A::test);
}
```

will compile and link.

[Documentation on the care and feeding of `static` members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

Comment: I liked your answer and it answered some questions, but why does "test2" need arguments for a constructor while "test" inside class A does not need arguments for a constructor when declared? Thanks

Comment: `static B test2;` is trying to define a variable that is an instance of a class. The program needs to construct this instance, so you have to provide the necessary arguments. `static A test;` is a declaration. Declarations just mean that the variable, function, type, or whatever exists. It doesn't make one. In a class, a `static` member variable is a declaration. Sometimes you can define the `static` member by initializing it in the class, but this is not one of those times.

Comment: Recommended reading: [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)